# Does maya in Advaita necessarily mean unreal?

Tags: brahman, advaita, brahma-sutras, adi-shankaracharya, maya

According to Advaita Vedanta, Jivatmas are all under maya and the universe too is made of maya. A jeevatma sees Brahman as Saguna which is too maya. When a Jivatma gets rid of this, merges with Brahman attaining the Highest State. Now, my question is whether Shankara ever say specifically in his commentary on the Brahma Sutras ever said maya is unreal? Is there any chance that maya can be real in Advaita Vedanta?

P.S. Please correct me if I am wrong about whatever I said about Advaita Vedanta in the first few lines.

Comment: There are nuanced differences between maya and the universe. Answers to the other Q address the physical universe for the most part. This Q may be reopened.

Comment: The word Maya itself implies that it is something that doesn't exist. Whether it is Real or unreal is irrelevant.

Comment: @moonstar2001, even if there is a small difference between 2 Qn-s, it's better for others to answer this Qn (+ that Qn). Otherwise the info will be splitted. So let this Qn remain as a useful link to the other Qn IMO.

Comment: The nature of Maya according them is not knowable.

Comment: @iammilind In that case, the 2 Qs must be merged  with this Q's nuance added to the other.